# How to find the critical numbers of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

I found the domain of this $$f\left( x\right) =\sqrt[3] {\left( x^{2}-4\right) ^{2}}$$ which are the Reals.

but I need to the critical numbers of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$

We calculate those derivatives to obtain :

$f'\left( x\right) =\dfrac{4x}{3\sqrt[3] {x^{2}-4}}$

$f''\left( x\right) =\dfrac{4\left( x^{2}-12\right) }{9\sqrt[3] {\left( x^{2}-4\right) ^{4}}}$

How do I find the critical numbers for $f'$ and $f''$?

For $f'(x) = 0$ I found $x = 0$ and when $f'(x) \nexists$ I found $x = 2$ and $x = -2$.

For $f''(x) = 0$ I found $x = 2 \sqrt{3}$ and $x = -2\sqrt{3}$ and $f''(x) \nexists$ I found $x = 2$ and $x = -2$

Are they correct?

Comment: You found them what else do you want ? The coordinates?

Comment: are they correct? When I try plugging those numbers in a variation table it looks weird. I feel like there should be less critical numbers.

Comment: chuck the equation in desmos if it looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\bbox[lightgreen]{\underline{{f^{'}(x)} = 0}}$:
$$
\dfrac{4x}{3\cdot\sqrt[3]{x^2 - 4}} = 0,\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
4\cdot{x}=0,\\
3\cdot\sqrt[3]{x^2 - 4}\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
x=0,\\
\sqrt[3]{x^2 - 4}\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
x=0,\\
{x^2 - 4}\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
x=0,\\
{x}\neq\pm{2}.
\end{cases}
$$
For $\bbox[lightgreen]{\underline{{f^{''}(x)} = 0}}$:
$$
\dfrac{4\cdot\left(x^{2}-12\right)}{9\cdot\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{2} - 4\right)^{4}}} = 0,\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
4\cdot\left(x^{2}-12\right)=0,\\
9\cdot\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{2} - 4\right)^{4}}\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
\left(x^{2}-12\right)=0,\\
\sqrt[3]{\left(x^{2} - 4\right)^{4}}\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
x=\pm{2}\sqrt{3},\\
\left(x^{2} - 4\right)^{4}\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
x=\pm{2}\sqrt{3},\\
\left(x^{2} - 4\right)\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
x=\pm{2}\sqrt{3},\\
x\neq\pm{2}.
\end{cases}
$$
They are correct.

Good luck!